# locating the corresponding jQuery code upon clicking on HTML

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-devtools, javascript-debugger

When jQuery code is separated from the HTML completely, code becomes a lot leaner and easier to maintain. But, that makes the debugging and exploring the underlying code more difficult to crack down.

My question is if there is an easy way ( using the Chrome DevTools ) to locate the corresponding jQuery code for some given HTML.

Let's break it down with an example. Say we've got an HTML like this;

`<i class="icon-chevron-right navigation-arrow"></i>`

This HTML displays a right arrow. Though the HTML does not suggest that this arrow is clickable, user do get the point and click on this arrow and things happen. Let's say that click brings the next testimonial into some div. And each click on that arrow keeps bringing the next testimonial and that's all there is to it.

Now... when you want to debug this, naturally, you turn on the dev tools panel and spot that arrow but then what...  There is no function name or anything like that that'll get you to the script.

We do know that there is some click event obviously tied to that icon but where is that code?

Perhaps, there is an easy way to figure this out. Hence the question.. .

Comment: Excellent question...  hoping to hear people's thoughts on this as well, as this would save me LOTS of time in the work I do.

Comment: You may find this usefull: [jQuery Audit Google Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jquery-audit/dhhnpbajdcgdmbbcoakfhmfgmemlncjg)

Answer (score 0):

I would add a `console.debug('arrow click handler called', this, arguments);` on the handler and you will have an appearance on the web developer console with a link to the source line which made the call. Should also work on other browsers.